# How can I specify argument in implementation of interface in PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have two intefaces and **First** uses **Second** as an argument but I can't use an implementation of **Second** as argument to **First**'s metod (Declaration must be compatible).
Is there any solutions or patterns for it?

Example:

```
interface iFirst
{
    public function fMethod(self $a) : bool;
}

interface iSecond {
    public function sMethod(iFirst $a);
}

class FirstImplemevtation implements iFirst
{
    public function fMethod(self $a) : bool //Declaration must be compatible
    {
    }
}

class SecondImplementation implements iSecond 
{
    public function sMethod(FirstImplemevtation  $a) //Declaration must be compatible
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify `iFirst` instead of `self` and `FirstImplemevtation` for argument hints.

Comment: Thanks but it's no what I looking for. I know how to fix errors but I looking for solution that could spicify input data (iFirst) to List's metod (iSecond->sMethod())